# How to access query execution history?

Tags: sql-server-2008, profiler

I want to know how long a certain query took to execute in SQL Server 2008. I could have known if I had put a Profiler trace on the process ID before I executed the query, but I forgot.

Is there any way to pull this information out of SQL Server without running the query again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the DMV sys.dm_exec_query_stats. There is a lot more information you can get from the query below such as reads/writes just use * to see all the information available.

```
SELECT 
t.TEXT QueryName,
last_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text( s.sql_handle ) t
```

Comment: More details available? Order by last executed etc.